# Limit amazon-s3 access to android app only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to create an Android app that used resources stored on amw s3.

I do not want users to login in the app, all I need is s3 files to be only accessible from my app.

If I got it right all I need to do is:

1. create the s3 bucket
2. add id pool
3. set unauth access
4. register the app on aws console

Is the above enough to make sure that s3 files can only be accessed by my app?

Thanks!

Comment: Create an IAM account with Programatic access and right policies.

Comment: Check Aws cognito, this exists to support also mobile aps so I would start there. Using programmatic access with hardcoded values is not a good idea. You need to authorize your application somehow and then you can allow it to get a temporary credentials.

Comment: Hello, thanks for suggestions. I have already checked both cognito and iam roles. But I was not able to find a solution. For me the only way to acheve this is by somehow registering application package and certificate.